# Angular: How to update an array object key value dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the points of selected object that in the exp below.

```
  $scope.players = [{
    name: 'Kobe',
    points: 10,
    asists: 0,
    rebounds: 0
  }, {
    name: 'Jordan',
    points: 20,
    asists: 0,
    rebounds: 0
  }, {
    name: 'Grant',
    points: 30,
    asists: 0,
    rebounds: 0
  }, 
  ];
```

and I assign an object selected with its name.

```
if($scope.playerName == $scope.players[i].name){
        $scope.selectedPlayerPoints = $scope.players[i].points;
        $scope.selectedPlayerAsists = $scope.players[i].asists;
        $scope.selectedPlayerRebounds = $scope.players[i].rebounds;
      }
```

but I can't update them:

```
$scope.selectedPlayerPoints.push(playerPoints);
```

To make it more clear please check: http://plnkr.co/edit/B8Nydni586Se79fDpjnq?p=preview

How it works: 
1-click on a player
2-click on points = each time 2 points will be added.
3-as you add more point, it will change the object dynamically..(but that is the problem..)

Thnx in advance!

Comment: You're just setting a new variable to the value rather than the actual variable address. Do something like:  $scope.selectedPlayer = $scope.players[i]   and then set the value on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but my guess is you have trouble with saving player points.

I've updated your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4WFtYyYrBmRN9gBVCfp). Basically instead of passing primitive values:

```
$scope.selectPlayer = function(name, points, asists, rebounds) { ... }
```

you should pass object reference:

```
$scope.selectPlayer = function(player) { ... }
```

Comment: I just see that your code doesn't update object either.. It does change the current points as a point added but it doesn't update current point to the object.. I selected this as correct answer because it gives me better idea..:) thnx

Comment: It updates points on a selected player, so not sure what you mean. Glad that it helped though.